# How to write to Discord's channel text box with selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to write into discord's channel message box using selenium C#.
[image: messageBox]
My problem is with finding the XPATH or how to identify the webElement.
This is my code currently

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V108.IndexedDB;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;
namespace discord
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://discord.com/channels/@me");
            Thread.Sleep(40000);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://discord.com/channels/@me/1036205803130077195");
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            By textBoxLocator = By.XPath("//*[@id=\"app-mount\"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/main/form/div/div[1]/div/div[3]");
            string message = "Discord test20";
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            IWebElement textBox = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(textBoxLocator));
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript($"arguments[0].value = '{message}';", textBox);
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("var event = new Event('keydown'); event.key = 'Enter'; arguments[0].dispatchEvent(event);", textBox);
        }
    }
}
```

I login manualy, then it goes to a channel with my other account and from there I get the message box Xpath stored in a var called texBox. I am using Javascript, because I was getting errors when I tried it with the SendKeys function.

```
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 'element not interactable
```

And this was my old code.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V108.IndexedDB;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;
namespace discord
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://discord.com/channels/@me");
            Thread.Sleep(40000);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://discord.com/channels/@me/1036205803130077195");
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            By textBoxLocator = By.XPath("//*[@id=\"app-mount\"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/main/form/div/div[1]/div/div[3]");

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            IWebElement textBox = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(textBoxLocator));
            actions.MoveToElement(textBox).Click().Perform();

            textBox.SendKeys("test 15");
            actions.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
        }
    }
}
```

HERE IS THE FULL HTML OF THE PAGE WHEN THERE IS NO INPUT IN THE FIELD:

```
<div class="textArea-2CLwUE textAreaSlate-9-y-k2 slateContainer-3x9zil">
  <div>
    <div class="placeholder-1rCBhr slateTextArea-27tjG0 fontSize16Padding-XoMpjI" aria-hidden="true">Message @Lex&lt;3</div>
    <div role="textbox" spellcheck="true" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-invalid="false" aria-autocomplete="list" class="markup-eYLPri editor-H2NA06 slateTextArea-27tjG0 fontSize16Padding-XoMpjI" autocorrect="off" data-can-focus="true" aria-label="Message @Lex
            <3" aria-multiline="true" data-slate-editor="true" data-slate-node="value" contenteditable="true" zindex="-1" style="position: relative; outline: none; white-space: pre-wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word; --darkreader-inline-outline: initial;" data-darkreader-inline-outline="">
      <div data-slate-node="element">
        <span data-slate-node="text">
          <span data-slate-leaf="true" class="emptyText-1o0WH_">
            <span data-slate-zero-width="n" data-slate-length="0">
              <br>
            </span>
          </span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

AND THIS IS HOW THE HTML CHANGES WHEN WE WRITE SOMETHING INTO THE TEXT FIELD:

```
<div class="textArea-2CLwUE textAreaSlate-9-y-k2 slateContainer-3x9zil">
  <div>
    <div role="textbox" spellcheck="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-invalid="false" aria-autocomplete="list" class="markup-eYLPri editor-H2NA06 slateTextArea-27tjG0 fontSize16Padding-XoMpjI" autocorrect="off" data-can-focus="true" aria-label="Message @Lex
            <3" aria-multiline="true" data-slate-editor="true" data-slate-node="value" contenteditable="true" zindex="-1" style="position: relative; outline: none; white-space: pre-wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word; --darkreader-inline-outline: initial;" data-darkreader-inline-outline="">
      <div data-slate-node="element">
        <span data-slate-node="text">
          <span data-slate-leaf="true" class="">
            <span data-slate-string="true">I wish you a happy day</span>
          </span>
        </span>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I suspect that the problem is with the Xpath. I will be incredibly grateful if someone can help me find how to message my alt account using selenium and the power of coding and C#

Comment: Could you post the HTML of the `textBox` element. It seems without credential cant check where is the issue.

Comment: @KunduK good suggestion, I did it.

Answer (score 0):

The Xpath was wrong. Here is what it should look like:
`//div[@class='textArea-2CLwUE textAreaSlate-9-y-k2 slateContainer-3x9zil']//div[@data-slate-node='value']`

And this is the code, now working!

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V108.IndexedDB;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;
namespace discord
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://discord.com/channels/@me");
            Thread.Sleep(40000);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://discord.com/channels/@me/1036205803130077195");
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            By textBoxLocator = By.XPath("//div[@class='textArea-2CLwUE textAreaSlate-9-y-k2 slateContainer-3x9zil']//div[@data-slate-node='value']");
            string message = "IT WORKS :)";
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            IWebElement textBox = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(textBoxLocator));
            textBox.SendKeys(message + Keys.Enter);
            


        }
    }
}
```